# Running Django in a "mixed" directory

Tags: django, iis, directory-structure

Is there a straightforward way to set up Django to operate on a directory or set of directories that will also serve other kinds of content?

Right now I have a webserver that is mostly running ColdFusion pages, but I'd like to start moving some sections over to Django. However, due to the existing directory structure it's not ideal to put all of the Django stuff in just one web path. Ideally I'd like to be able to keep using the original directory structure rather than having to use a lot of redirects.

Is there any way to make Django play nice with other things, or does it pretty much need its own root to be happy? The only other solution I can think of is carefully configuring the web server with a lot of rules that purposefully sidestep Django when necessary (for example, instructing it to manually handle anything with a file extension, or to ignore certain directories).

This would be on IIS, if it happened.

Comment: Do you have to manage users?  Dynamic content?  If so, which system  will be responsible for users and database interaction?  If both systems interact with the database, do they have to sync, or will you be able to operate them in separate silos?

Comment: @Ted: It might be smart, especially if the logins are on the ColdFusion side, to write an auth plugin for Django that says `isAuthenticated()` if ColdFusion says it is.  A bit roundabout, but I've done it.

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to have to set up cross-site authentication somehow. Users will probably be managed by the existing legacy (ColdFusion) system. Actually, it would be easier if I was dealing with dynamic content. The problem is that there is a lot of static content that for various reasons can't be moved to a CMS, so it has to be served statically.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure URLs in Django anyway you like. Have a look at the [URL dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/). So say for instance your site www.example.com, you decide to have /wiki and /blog be developed using Django. You can configure IIS to redirect those urls to Django, while the rest of www.example.com/everythingelse is served by Coldfusion or whatever.

Even a mixed url scheme say /store/mycoldfusion-product-view and /store/django-product-view would be possible though this would require some amount of fancy redirect code depending on your setup.

Comment: How would I set that up? So far I've been using WSGI with Apache httpd on a Linux machine, and in all of those cases there is just one entry point (`/`) to the project.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't be clear. I meant that in the **past**, I have set everything up using modwsgi. But **now** I will be using IIS, which I'm not familiar with in terms of Django integration. Obviously I can't use modswgi with IIS.

Comment: Sorry my bad. Have you looked at this - https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoOnWindowsWithIISAndSQLServer?

Comment: Yes. I haven't tried setting it up yet, but it really looks like when set up it'd interfere pretty strongly with other executables? (It tells you to set up IIS to create an association for *).

Comment: I haven't done this myself so I can't say for sure. But this section - https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoOnWindowsWithIISAndSQLServer#SettingupIIS seems to indicate that all you have to do is create a Virtual directory in IIS and indicate that it is handled by the ISAPI extension. From what I can tell, it will not effect any of the other directories configured on IIS.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you have some control over what is being served when.  If that's the case, could you use a reverse proxy to segment your namespace?  I do this with a lot of different projects; I use nginx, and tell it "these paths are for Wordpress, these paths are for Django, and these paths are for images and other static content."

That's an excellent way of making Django "play nice," as long as you have a disciplined approach to converting some of the paths to one or the other.

Comment: I should have looked closer and spotted the IIS tag.  There is an Nginx for Windows, though.

Comment: I think switching from IIS to nginx is going to be a pretty hard sell.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. You don't run nginx instead of IIS, you run in alongside IIS.  I run my appservers on ports 8000, 8001, and so on, and Nginx on port 80.  It forwards the HTTP request to a given port based on criteria specified in its configuration, usually about the HTTP path requested.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have that kind of leeway. Otherwise it'd probably be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to set this up would be to daisy chain: 
Webserver -> django -> response middleware -> subprocess/pipe/httplib -> coldfusion.

The response middleware would pseudo code something like this:
if response.code in [list of ok responses]:
  return
else:
  call coldfusion

The advantage of this method would be that you can transition at whatever rate you want.  The disadvantage is that it isn't a simple configuration, daisy chains are brittle by nature, and the daisy chain might break.